# Picker View constraints iphone4/iphone5

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode5, autolayout

I have a picker view on ios7. 
This picker view as at the bottom of the view controller. 
On the iPhone 5 it displays fine, and its big enough to see the options in the picker view.

On the iPhone 4 it is too small to see the options in the picker view.

I know I have to use constraints, but any idea which way to go with this one.

The picker view is stuck to the bottom of the vc.

thanks

Comment: can you put image of both ?

Comment: I am sorry i don't understand ? An image on here ?

Comment: are you creating it in storyboard or programmatically?

Comment: its on main controller so its on my storyboard

Answer (score 0):

In storyboard, simply ctrl-click-drag to the view you want to make the constraint with like this:

[image]

and then you can see all your constraints on the right side of Xcode:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In simple way.

Click on the picker and click on the "`Add missing Constraints`"

[image]